# How to generate Semantic Model from code file without project file using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I have two file as below:

```
namespace a
{
    Class Audi
    {
            public string Model(string a)
            {           
               Benz obj= new Benz();
               var str=obj.BenzDetails();
               return str;

            }
    }
}
namespace a
{
    Class Benz 
    {
            public string BenzDetails()
            {           
              return "some details";
            }
    }
}
```

I need to get all objects created in Audi Class (Global or local). Also i need to get details of methods invoked using these declared object.

For example in these 2 classes, for Audi class need:

- Object created :- obj
- Method invoked using this object :- BenzDetails
- name of class whose object is created: Benz
- namespace of that class:   a

I am able to get list of declared objects in a class with this code:

```
 var lstLocalObjects = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>()
                                                .Where(x => x.Declaration.Variables.Any(p => p.Initializer.Value.Kind().ToString().Equals("ObjectCreationExpression", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

I have syntax tree, I don't know how to generate Semantic Model.
Is it possible to get above details using syntax tree only. Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `Compilation` by calling [`CSharpCompilation.Create()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/CSharpCompilation.cs,210), passing your `SyntaxTree` and the necessary references (at least `mscorlib`).

You can then call `GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree)`.

Comment: @Gerry, just look at the [simple example](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/master/samples/CSharp/APISamples/Compilations.cs#L21) that create a simple `Compilation`. For your example just add invocation of `GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree tree, bool ignoreAccessibility)` from `Compilation`

Comment: It throws exception : MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata